# Unexpected unchecked conversion warning

Tags: java, generics

Can anyone explain why there is an untyped conversion warning on y assignment line? Note that there is no warning on either x or z assignments.

```
public class Entity<T>
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <TX> Entity<TX> typed( Class<TX> type )
    {
        return (Entity<TX>) this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <TX> Entity<TX> typed( Entity<?> entity,  Class<TX> type )
    {
        return (Entity<TX>) entity;
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args )
    {
        final Entity<?> a = new Entity<Integer>();
        final Entity b = (Entity) a;

        final Entity<Integer> x = a.typed( Integer.class );
        final Entity<Integer> y = b.typed( Integer.class );
        final Entity<Integer> z = typed( b, Integer.class );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your entity, `b`, is untyped after the cast from `a`, so it's untyped when you convert it back with `b.typed(Integer.class)`.  Generic types are unlike class types; they are not retained when "downcasted."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`b` is of type `Entity`, which is a raw type. Therefore its API looks like this:

```
public Entity typed(Class type)
```

So you're converting from `Entity` to `Entity<Integer>`. The compiler has lost any correlation between the `type` parameter and the kind of entity returned, so it can't do any checking.

To put it another way, you could use:

```
final Entity<Integer> y = b.typed(String.class);
```

... and still receive only the same warning. If you try the same change with `x` or `z`, you'll get a compile-time error instead.

EDIT: As noted in comments, the fact that you're using a raw type removes all traces of generics.

From [JLS section 4.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, it is possible to use as a type the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw type.

And then in [section 4.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6):

> Type erasure also maps the signature (§8.4.2) of a constructor or method to a signature that has no parameterized types or type variables. The erasure of a constructor or method signature s is a signature consisting of the same name as s and the erasures of all the formal parameter types given in s.

Comment: Note that "typed" method is itself parameterized. There are two type parameters.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik: That doesn't matter - when you call a method on a raw type, that all goes away.

Comment: Except that the compiler isn't saying that I am calling a method on a raw type. It is saying that I am doing an unchecked conversion in the assignment from Entity to Entity<Integer>. The type if fully specified by TX.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik: But `TX` doesn't exist on the call, because you're calling it on a raw type. As it happens, using `javac` from Java 7 on your code *also* gives a warning that you're calling a method on a raw type: "Test.java:21: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to `<TX>typed(Class<TX>)` as a member of the raw type `Entity`" (and more details).

Comment: Thanks. The quote from section 4.6 is the explanation that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From the declaration:

```
final Entity<?> a = new Entity<Integer>();
```

`a` is typed, so the method call is `a.typed( Integer.class )` is also typed.

In `typed( b, Integer.class )` it works because the method is generic.

But in

```
final Entity b = (Entity) a;
```

you have turned-off generics (for `b` by using the raw-type instead of the generic-version of `Entity`) so the invocation `b.typed( Integer.class )` is untyped. So you get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You are "downcasting" a, removing it's type identifier when assigning to b.  Because b is now untyped, you are getting an untyped conversion warning because it no longer knows the type.